# Does Encryption on Encryption help?

Tags: encryption, passwords, hash

Is hashing a password multiple times and then encrypting a text with the hashed password more secure than hashing a password fewer times and encrypting the text multiple times recursively?

Comment: If your password is "password" then both schemes are equally secure. If your encryption algorithm is a linear equation then both schemes are equally secure. I could go on but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no generic answer to this. It depends on the actual hash and encryption algorithms and whatever "multiple times" and "fewer" actually mean.

But I think that the general idea of this approach is wrong. Instead of trying to add security by doing hashing/encryption multiple times you should start with a known strong key derivation function (and not a simple fast hash, even if called multiple times) to derive a strong key from the password and then use a known strong encryption method. In other words: use known good primitives as they are intended and don't invent your own enhanced version of weaker primitives.

Comment: Indeed, it's similar to putting 3 identical doors to your hose entrance compared to putting a stronger one.